# How to compress image before upload on amzon s3 server using c# .net?

Tags: c#, image, amazon-s3

Hello i have done api for image upload on amzon s3 server with web api c#.but i want to before upload image need this image to compress but how can do that i don't know.

This is my api =>

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("FileUpload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage FileUpload()
    {
        try
        {               
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName.ToString());
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                    Image img = null;
                    string newFileName = "";
                    string path = "";
                   img = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);
                    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"].ToString();
                    newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff") + ".jpeg";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);

            SaveJpg(img, filePath); // here i have call method for the save image in my local system. 

                    var client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                    try
                    {
                        PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                         {
                             BucketName = "abc",
                             InputStream = postedFile.InputStream, // i need this image compress but how can do  
                             Key = path + newFileName
                         };
                        PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(putRequest);
                    }
                    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
                    {
                        if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                            (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                            ||
                            amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Status);
                }
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }            
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done");
    }
```

This is my ImageCompress method =>

```
public static void SaveJpg(Image image, string file_name, long compression = 60)
    {
        try
        {
            EncoderParameters encoder_params = new EncoderParameters(1);

            encoder_params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);

            ImageCodecInfo image_codec_info =
                GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

            image.Save(file_name, image_codec_info, encoder_params);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is my api and i need this image to before upload image compress and then after i want to upload this image so any one idea how can do that please let me know.

Comment: Jpeg is already compressed image format.

Comment: @Reniuz yes i know this thing but i want to more make compress image so how can do that any idea about it.

Comment: zip it or something.

Comment: Start by reviewing the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level

Comment: You will get lots of money if you find out! (Read: You will not be able to improve on the jpeg compression!) - But you can influence the resulting size by lowering the quality. - (Btw: zipping will not help but more likely hurt!)

Comment: @Takarii this link with code is worked but how can do in my code have you idea any?

Comment: I have an idea. You have an example so write same logic in your code.

Comment: ok i will edit my question and before have the code some i have write.

Comment: @Reniuz i have edit my question can you please help me

Comment: @Reniuz i have before write this code for the image save in my local system but now i want to save image on amzon server so now i want to change my code but i have not idea how can do that

Comment: @Reniuz can you help me please.

Comment: Documentation documentation documentation...start reading it and it will save yours and others time. In [image.Save()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation you can see that you can save image to Stream. And that stream could replace `postedFile.InputStream`